# Applying one or more XSLT stytle sheet on an XML data in java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

i want to be able to apply one or more sytle sheets on an xml data. i have this code and i am wondering how i can modify it so i can apply as many style sheets on  a single xml data and the result be printed on the text area of a GUI ( as i presume settext() accepts only strings) and saved on a file at the same time. these are my codes.. thank you

```
   /**
   * Constructor for objects of class Simple
   */
    public Simple(String xmlFile, String xslFile,String outputFile)
   {
   this.xmlFile = xmlFile;
   this.xslFile = xslFile;
   this.outputFile= outputFile;
   }

  public String SimpleTransform() throws   

 TransformerException,TransformerConfigurationException,FileNotFoundException,
 IOException

  {String mystring = "";

 TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslFile)); 
 transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xmlFile), new StreamResult(new   
 FileOutputStream(outputFile)));
  return mystring = "***The result is in birds.out *****";
 } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need transformation filter chain: Read [Concatenating Transformations with a Filter Chain](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPXSLT8.html)